# bigrquery: Error with Google Big Query R interface

Tags: r, google-api, bigdata, google-oauth, google-bigquery

I'm using bigrquery R package to fetch the data. But i'm getting the following error. Let me know if anyone knows how to fix this error.

```
"Waiting for authentication in browser...
Authentication complete.
Loading required package: rjson
Error: Invalid access credentials have been reset. Please try again.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
  Unrecognized CURL options: token.error
2: In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
  Unrecognized CURL options: token.error"
```

Comment: Can you tell me what versions of httr and bigrquery you were using?